# Call two functions simultaneously from a combobox?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created two functions that must start at the same time as soon as I select the items of a combobox. I tried to make them start together by writing: combo_Campionato ['values'] = combo_campionato (), filter_campionato (). The first function by importing the combobox items. The second function ensures that, by selecting an item in the combobox, the rows displayed in the grid are "filtered" according to the selected combobox item.

But I get this error:

```
    combo_Campionato['values'] = combo_campionati(), filtra_campionato()
TypeError: filtra_campionato() missing 1 required positional argument: 'campionato'
```

If I delete the name of the second function, and leave only the first one working, the script starts correctly:  combo_Campionato ['values'] = combo_campionato ()

This is the code:

```py
def combo_campionati():
    campionato = combo_Campionato.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT Nome_Campionato FROM ARCHIVIO_CAMPIONATI')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

def filtra_campionato(campionato): 
    campionato = combo_Campionato.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ARCHIVIO_Risultati WHERE campionato=?',(campionato,))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return results

#Combobox Campionati
lbl_Campionato = Label(root, text="Campionato", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#E95420", fg="white")
lbl_Campionato.place(x=6, y=60)
combo_Campionato = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, textvariable=campionato, state="readonly")
combo_Campionato.place(x=180, y=60)
combo_Campionato.set("Seleziona campionato")
combo_Campionato['values'] = combo_campionati(), filtra_campionato()
combo_Campionato.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_squadre)
```

I don't know if I'm moving on in the right way. If I'm wrong, how can I call those two functions at the same time when I select the combobox items? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get an error is - You need to pass a variable inside the function `filtra_campionato`. For e.g. - something like - `filtra_campionato(something)`

So, instead of this -

```
def filtra_campionato(campionato): 
    campionato = combo_Campionato.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ARCHIVIO_Risultati WHERE campionato=?',(campionato,))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return results
```

Remove the `campionato` in the () because it is not needed -

```
def filtra_campionato(): 
    campionato = combo_Campionato.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ARCHIVIO_Risultati WHERE campionato=?',(campionato,))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result
```

You need - `return result` not `return results` because it is singular in the `result=[row[0] for row in cursor]`. Python interprets it as different variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I remove "campionato", I will get the error: NameError: name 'results' is not defined. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Thats because of the spelling error :). Look at edit.

Comment: spelling error? Why?

Comment: `results` and `result` look at last lines of first and second code.

Comment: I hope you got this.

Comment: Yes please. I made a typo. I was tired. Can you explain your answer please? Why did you say remove league ()? Why is it not necessary? A second question:, (league,)) what's the use in that case? (I'm not talking about my code, but I'm talking from the general logical point of view of python code)

Comment: Actually, what you did was passing a variable - `filtra_campionato(campionato)`. You pass a variable only when you need to access it inside the function. But, `campionato = combo_Campionato.get()` completely changes `campionato`, so, you are not accessing the variable but making a new variable. Therefore, passing a variable is not needed.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. And :, (campionato,)) afer WHERE campionato=?' what's the use in that case , (campionato,) ?

Comment: I don't know that, because it may be a different thing, look at [this](https://www.mcobject.com/docs/Content/Programming/Python/Classes/Cursor/execute.htm) for info about that.

Comment: That is fine. I thank you. You're kind. If you can, can you take a look at this question I just posted? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349626/filter-database-records-through-combobox-and-view-in-grid-treeview